# Image not showing after saving

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to compute an image with points plotted on it, and it seems to work well when I am showing it :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18))

ax = fig.add_subplot(222)
img = imageio.imread(stim_dir + image_name)

# Code to plot points

plt.title("fixation points of " + file_name)
plt.show()
```

It shows me the image I want, no worries. However, if I just add to this code

```
plt.savefig(result_dir + file_name + ".png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Then it saves the image to the right folder, but it is all blank, without any title, any image, any points. Just blank. What could go wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the order of `plt.savefig(result_dir + file_name + ".png", bbox_inches='tight')` and `plt.show()`. So if you first save the image and then show it, the saved image should not be blank anymore.

Comment: Oh it was this simple ! Thank you. Do you know why it happens, do the "plot" closes when we show it ?

Comment: @Sanimys `plt.show` clears the figure you built.